# Historian tool for Lollipop devices 5.0

Tags: android

I want to explore about Historian tool provided in 5.0 OS. I tried having looks at many forums found these 2 as good
http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/played-android-l-battery-historian-tool-t2808146
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html

Also the steps followed by me are

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats --enable full-wake-history
```

perform some operations.

```
adb bugreport > bugreport.txt
```

collect bugReport.

```
./historian.py -a bugreport.txt > battery.html
```

This will generate anhtml file about batterystats.
Also I am trying for a particular package with this command

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats --charged <package-name>
```

But I dont see much usefull information related to my package which I can analyse and modify some code.
Or any one can pass on some useful links where some description is given related to the html file generated or any information which you can share so that i can too make it efficient.

Comment: I too am interested in figuring out how to get correct battery stats on Lollipop for a specific package. When I try running dumpsys batterystats on a lollipop device the output is not in the format that historian is looking for. This same command works perfect on pre-L

Answer (score 0):

Google's Colt McAnlus wrote a document he titled '*Colt's **Unofficial** guide to getting started with Battery Historian*'

Here is a link to his Google+ post for the release of this document:

https://plus.google.com/rop/1/wm/1/+ColtMcAnlis/posts/foNLrMKDBUa

It runs through a couple of examples about how to interpret the output of the battery historian chart.